# How to hide all inline comments on phabricator?

Tags: phabricator

I'd like to hide (or collapse, if not possible) all the comments within phabricator.

I know I could just download the `.diff` and read it from there but I would just want a quick way/keyboard shortcut to hide all the comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you scroll down a little bar appears at the top of the screen with a hamburger menu where you have the option to hide all comments

Answer (score 0):

You can save this as a bookmarklet to remove all the comments.

```
javascript:document.querySelectorAll('.differential-inline-comment').forEach(n => n.parentNode.removeChild(n));
```